# Rewrite a complicated sentence

Tags: paraphrasing, run-on-sentences

Suppose I have been given a sentence to rewrite it without changing its meaning. Then I tried my best to write another form of given sentence. And after writing my sentence I went to the person, who has given the sentence, to ask him- Whether my sentence is right or wrong and whether it conveys the same meaning or not. Can I use the following sentence to ask him? i.e, does the following sentence make any sense?

- If I write the above sentence in the following way, do you think that the following sentence can be considered as a correct with having similar meaning of your given sentence/ with having as like as meaning that your sentence has. (I want to say this sentence to this person).

Answer (score 2):

A *paraphrase* is a rewording that conveys the same meaning. You can say:

> Is this an accurate paraphrase of your sentence?: ___

Answer (score 1):

Not bad. I would say:

> If I write the above sentence in the following way, do you think that **this sentence** can be considered as *correct*, **having a meaning similar to** your given sentence?

*this sentence* - you don't need to repeat "following sentence" as it is already understood.

*correct* is not a noun, so no article is used.

Instead of *like* use *similar* and rephrase a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In any language praising a person would draw attention towards you.So if you are referring a well esteemed Lecturer or professor you can ask him in this way

> May i have the honor to know whether this sentence is conveying the same meaning as prior sentence.